# enabling Apache's HostnameLookups, can't find it in httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to enable `HostnameLookups`. I opened `httpd.conf` but couldn’t find any`HostnameLookups`. Do I need to add a line myself and what's the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups):

> This directive enables DNS lookups so that host names can be logged
>   (and passed to CGIs/SSIs in REMOTE_HOST). The value Double refers to
>   doing double-reverse DNS lookup. That is, after a reverse lookup is
>   performed, a forward lookup is then performed on that result. At least
>   one of the IP addresses in the forward lookup must match the original
>   address. (In "tcpwrappers" terminology this is called PARANOID.)
>
> Regardless of the setting, when mod_authz_host is used for controlling
>   access by hostname, a double reverse lookup will be performed. This is
>   necessary for security. Note that the result of this double-reverse
>   isn't generally available unless you set HostnameLookups Double. For
>   example, if only HostnameLookups On and a request is made to an object
>   that is protected by hostname restrictions, regardless of whether the
>   double-reverse fails or not, CGIs will still be passed the
>   single-reverse result in REMOTE_HOST.
>
> The default is Off in order to save the network traffic for those
>   sites that don't truly need the reverse lookups done. It is also
>   better for the end users because they don't have to suffer the extra
>   latency that a lookup entails. Heavily loaded sites should leave this
>   directive Off, since DNS lookups can take considerable amounts of
>   time. The utility logresolve, compiled by default to the bin
>   subdirectory of your installation directory, can be used to look up
>   host names from logged IP addresses offline.
>
> Finally, if you have hostname-based Require directives, a hostname
>   lookup will be performed regardless of the setting of HostnameLookups.

Answer (score 3):

[HostnameLookups](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups) is part of the core of apache so you just have to add the line in the configuration file.

Be careful though, the dns lookup on client IP is often slow and unreliable (a lot of IP address don't have a reverse record in the DNS).

Answer (score 1):

What distribution are you using? If you're using Ubuntu, on a standard Apache install, you'll find it in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off
```